# python3 как из .py сделать apk?

Tags: python, python-3.x, apk

как из .py сделать apk?
python 3.8.7

Comment: https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android
Тут есть ответ на твой вопрос

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+apk

Comment: Никак. ((( Кому надо — лучше сразу джаву учить...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Единственный вариант для Python 3.6+ - это Python for Android, приложение на kivy.

P. S.

> Никак. ((( Кому надо — лучше сразу джаву учить... – Victor VosMottor

Сделать можно, но в принципе на Java удобнее.

Comment: и kotlin как альтернатива